# Using custom map with MKMapKit

Tags: iphone, dictionary, ios4, mapkit, mkmapview

I am creating an iPhone app for OS4.0, and I am attempting to integrate a custom map with a standard MKMapView. I have been provided a map in .eps format (vector image), and I want to somehow overlay this on an MKMapView in and restrict the scrolling boundaries of the map so users cannot scroll outside the boundaries of the custom map. What's the best way to go about this?

I have read some stuff about hosting map tiles on a server, but this seems overly complex for my application. This would just be a map for an attraction roughly the size of a public zoo, so I would think that it would be conceivable to just convert the .eps to a .png file, and overlay it, but this might not give the best performance.

I understand that I could conceivable use a UIScrollView to do the job, but the problem is that I have dynamically generated MKPinAnnotationViews placed on the map, whose position must be based on latitude and longitude, so I can't think on an elegant or reasonable way to do it with a scrollview. Any ideas?

Thanks!
-Matt

Comment: There is an Apple demo of it but you probably have to have a paid enrolment to download it. I've done it before but with custom polygons and its no mean feat and possibly beyond being able to post it here.

Comment: Vector image formats such as pdf do not perform particularly well when scrolling and zooming. You need to break the eps into pngs and use the TileMap code as suggested below. You improve performance, but it can drastically increase the size of your app depending on the size of the vector image/number of zoom levels supported etc. If the image is not too large (will fit into memory for the worst device you are targeting), you can get away with placing the png in a scroll view.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a great bit of example code that will show you what you need to do.  Check out the TileMap sample - it is available as part of the (free) WWDC 2010 samples download.

It shows you how to use the gdal2tiles utility to convert an input map into a tree of overlay tiles.

Another good bit of Apple sample code to check out is HazardMap, which is part of the regular SDK samples.